# Function not running in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to learn MATLAB and this function should convert the amount of years entered to seconds. The file is saved as seconds.m

```
function x = seconds(years)
    x = years*365*24*60*60;

years = input('How many years do you want to know in seconds? ');
seconds(years)
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: I would always recommend you outsourcing most functions into a separate .m file. It helps keeping large projects clean. And you miss an "end" after x = ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions, depending on what you want to do:

**Run the script from a single file**

You would then need to define two functions and make sure you `end` each function. This would look like this when stored in a file called `main.m`:

```
function x = seconds(years)
    x = years*365*24*60*60;
end

function main()
    years = input('How many years do you want to know in seconds? ');
    seconds(years)
end
```

**Store the script across two files**

The script stored in `seconds.m` would look like this:

```
function x = seconds(years)
    x = years*365*60*60
end
```

The script stored in `main.m` would look like this:

```
years = input('How many years do you want to know in seconds? ');
seconds(years)
```

You would have to run the `main.m` script.

Comment: Note that as of R2016b, you can also add local functions to the end of script files. Docs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html